# Class Cast Exception in REST call from android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get List of items from my web application `MyApp` running on server server `172.16.xx.15` from my android app using `resttemplate`.
Everything works fine when I do like

```
String url="http://172.16.xx.15:8080/MyApp/GetAllItem";

RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

List<LinkedHashMap> items=restTemplate.getForObject(url, List.class);
```

Above code works fine when I make above url access anonymously. But I am using spring security at server end, I need to authenticate user before accessing this list of items. So I am trying to get same list of items with authentication. I am using following code:

```
String username="test"
String password="test"
HttpAuthentication authHeader=new HttpBasicAuthentication(username, password)  
HttpHeaders requestHeaders=new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setAuthorization(authHeader);
requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
 RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
 List<LinkedHashMap> items=(List<LinkedHashMap>)restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders), List.class);
```

This code also works somewhat but throwing error and application crashing.

> java.lang.ClassCastException:org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
>   cannot be cast to java.util.List

please help in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are directly casting the response of exchange which is ResponseEntity into your collection

You need to collect first as

```
ReaponseEntity<List<LinkedHashMap>> response
```

Then on above call the

```
response.getBody()
```

Comment: thanks for help. One more thing. how to just authenticate user means true or false.

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<LinkedHashMap> items=(List<LinkedHashMap>)restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders), List.class);
```

`restTemplate.exchange` method returns a `ResponseEntity<T>` object so it is absolutely normal to get the `ClassCastException`. You need to rewrite your above line to something like this:

```
ResponseEntity<<LinkedHashMap>> entity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders), List.class);
List<LinkedHashMap> items = entity.getBody()
```